# how do i make a notification disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm failing to make a notification that will disappear after about 1 second whilst keeping items on the page a little darkened or faded (to appear as though in the background). Little knowledge of JavaScript here.

```js
var notification = document.getElementById("one");
setTimeout(function() {
  notification.close()
}, 1000)
```

```css
body {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.notification {
  transition: all 0.35s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#1abc9c, #16a085);
  border-bottom: 0.125rem solid #1abc9c;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 0.25rem 0.25rem 0;
}

.notification .content {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="notification">
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is a notification</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>This is a text that i copied from someone: My father had a small estate in default link Nottinghamshire: I was the third of five sons. He sent me to Emanuel College in Cambridge at fourteen years old, where I resided three years, and applied myself
    close to my studies; but the charge of maintaining me, although I had a very scanty allowance, being too great for a narrow fortune, I was bound apprentice to Mr. James Bates, an eminent surgeon in London, with whom I continued four years. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: what about setTimeout(function(){notification.hide()}, 1000) ?, Even that, I would recommend you to use [JavaScript Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

Comment: Are you using a library or framework of some sort? `.close()` isn't a JavaScript method for anything other than the window and document.

Comment: @maguri hide is a jQuery function and doesn't work on regular DOM elements. And notifications look like a great feature but aren't much use if you are required to support IE.

Comment: You right! (the habit)

Comment: You can do that without JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the `.close()` to `.style.visibility = 'hidden'`


The `close()` function is not a native JavaScript function to hide DOM elements.

```js
var notification = document.getElementById("one");
setTimeout(function() {
  notification.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}, 1000)
```

```css
body {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.notification {
  transition: all 0.35s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#1abc9c, #16a085);
  border-bottom: 0.125rem solid #1abc9c;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 0.25rem 0.25rem 0;
}

.notification .content {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="notification">
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is a notification</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>This is a text that i copied from someone: My father had a small estate in default link Nottinghamshire: I was the third of five sons. He sent me to Emanuel College in Cambridge at fourteen years old, where I resided three years, and applied myself
    close to my studies; but the charge of maintaining me, although I had a very scanty allowance, being too great for a narrow fortune, I was bound apprentice to Mr. James Bates, an eminent surgeon in London, with whom I continued four years. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

notification.style.display = "none";

or, notification.style.visibility = "hidden";